# Java to NPAPI for Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, npapi

I was wondering if it is possible to make an NPAPI plugin from a Java project (Since java can be compiled straight to a dll with the help of [gcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/))? I already looked at the [mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Plugins) describing NPAPI plugins but I could not find anything related to Java. All the tools over seem to focus on C++ projects.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tools and examples focus on C/C++ because NPAPI is a C API. There's no way to make an NPAPI plugin purely in Java.

If you *really* wanted to, you could probably write a bridge layer in C using JNI, but that means you'd need to have your plugin start a JVM. If your plugin were running in a browser that doesn't run plugins out-of-process though, you'd potentially be running two JVMs in the same process, which might not end well. And getting the drawing right across the bridge will be a nightmare, at least on the Mac.

Before trying to go down that route, you should ask yourself why, if your goal is to run Java code in a browser, you aren't just using the Java plugin.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpfull. I wanted to write an extension that prints a receipt on a specific local printer when a javascript function was called on a specific webpage. I had already legacy java code in my possession that could communicate with these specific printers.